# Dialog Interface Follow-Up

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a follow up to a previous question I posted about a product ordering system. Currently, the code that was written to solve an original issue does not work after revising to my needs, and I am unable to figure out the issue.

I have tried many methods but cannot figure out what is preventing the order from copying to the order form.

This is the current dialog form:
[image]

This is the current Order Sheet(Where the order should be copied to):
[image]

This is the part list that the dialog is pulling data from:
[image]

This is the moveToOrder Debug Log:
[image]
This is the complete code.gs page (The other html pages have not been changed at all)

```
function clearOrder(){

  //Clears the Current Order Form and Quantities
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var setsheet = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[1])
  var toclear = setsheet.getRange("E2:E100")
  var clear = toclear.clearContent()
  var ss = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0])
  var clearRange = ss.getRange("A4:E100")
  var clearData = clearRange.clearContent()
  var dateRange = ss.getRange("A1:E1")
  var clearDate = dateRange.clearContent()


}

function printOrder(){

  //Selects the Applicable Cells to be Printed
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var dateRange = ss.getRange("C1:E1")
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var formatDate = dateRange.setNumberFormat("dddd, m/d/yy");
  var addDate = dateRange.setValue(currentDate)
  var textRange = ss.getRange("A1:B1")
  var addText = textRange.setValue("Order Compiled On:")
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()
  var finRange = ss.getRange("A1:E"+ lastRow)
  var printRange = ss.setActiveRange(finRange)


}



function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Order Materials')
  .addItem('Show Order Dialog', 'displayOrderDialog')
  .addToUi();
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function displayOrderDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('dialog').evaluate().setWidth(600).setHeight(300).setTitle('Inventory');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface,'Product List');
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Order').activate();
}

function getInventory() {//show order dialog for selecting parts
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Part List');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var pA=rg.getValues();
  var html="<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>";
  html+='<tr><th>Brand</th><th>Product Description</th><th>Size and Type</th><th>Item Number</th><th>Quantity</th><th>&nbsp;</tr>';
  for(var i=0;i<pA.length;i++) {    
       html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><input type="text" value="%s" id="%s" size="6" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Order" onClick="moveToOrder(\'%s\',\'%s\');"/></tr>',pA[i][0],pA[i][1],pA[i][2].toString().replace(/(")/g,'\\"'),pA[i][3],pA[i][4],Number(i+2),pA[i][2],i+2);
  }

  html+='</table>';
  var orderObj={html:html};
  return orderObj;
}

function moveToOrder(orderObj) { //moves selected part to active page so make sure your on the right order form
  //orderObj['remaining']=debitInventory(orderObj);

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Part List');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,1,4);
  var pA=rg.getValues();
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName('Order');
  pA[0].splice(pA[0].length,0,orderObj.quantity);
  osh.appendRow(pA[0]);
  return orderObj;
}
```

The printOrder and clearOrder functions are written by me and have nothing to do with the order dialog, but I figured the complete sheet would be best. Thank you.

Here is the link to a copy of the sheet(you should be able to access the code from there). Feel free to edit however needed:

[Spreadsheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dnTDYiTMz8jmwnaDW6AuyzaaQGJIqn_UsaoGRzQUg0A/edit?usp=sharing)
   [Script Link](https://script.google.com/d/1plhqqIqBhZwaKeEtkHAVW3qL4bawPMDsPPzKFdlSFHr2mQv7paL_CiF7/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Perhaps `var osh=ss.getActiveSheet();` should be this `var osh=ss.getSheetByName('Order');` It was set in `displayOrderDialog()` but you may have moved to another sheet.

Comment: @Cooper That does not help... I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the html + ='<tr>...etc and the for loop and how they get and store the data because I changed the formatting and the table from what you had originally written.

Comment: Are you getting any console log errors?

Comment: @Cooper No, I am not

Comment: What does the inventory sheet look like now?

Comment: @Cooper I updated the post with a picture of it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you added a column to the parts list but didn't add the value for that `<td></td>` so  I think this might solve one problem `html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><input type="text" value="%s" id="%s" size="6" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Order" onClick="moveToOrder(\'%s\',\'%s\');"/></tr>',pA[i][0],pA[i][1],pA[i][2],pA[i][3],pA[i][4],"inv-"+ Number(i+2),pA[i][2],i+2,"q-"+ Number(i+2));`

I also noticed that you now have quotes in your size and type and possibly in other places so I think you will have to search for quotes in your data and escape them and that's probably why it's not copying now. But honestly I can't be sure.

There are " quotes inside of your size and type data as shown below:

[image]

Most likely your getting a malformed html error.

You can probably use something like this `pA[i][2].toString().replace(/"/g,'\\"');`

So then the html line becomes something like this:

`html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><input type="text" value="%s" id="%s" size="6" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Order" onClick="moveToOrder(\'%s\',\'%s\');"/></tr>',pA[i][0],pA[i][1],pA[i][2].toString().replace(/(")/g,'\\"'),pA[i][3],pA[i][4],"inv-"+ Number(i+2),pA[i][2],i+2,"q-"+ Number(i+2));`

I've tried to make this as clear as I can.  I rewrote the code in a little different way so that header column headers can be used to identify the data.

```
function getInventory() {//show order dialog for selecting parts
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Part List');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var pA=rg.getValues();
  var dObj={};
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].map(function(r){return r.replace(/ /g,'');});
  var html="<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>";
  html+='<tr><th>Brand</th><th>Product Description</th><th>Size and Type</th><th>Item Number</th><th>Quantity</th><th>&nbsp;</tr>';
  for(var i=0;i<pA.length;i++) {  
    for(var j=0;j<pA[i].length;j++) {
      dObj[hA[i][j]]=pA[i][j];
    }  
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><input type="text" value="%s" id="%s" size="6" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Order" onClick="moveToOrder(\'%s\',\'%s\');"/></tr>',dObj.Brand,dObj.ProductDescription,dObj.SizeandType.replace(/(")/g,'\\"'),dObj.ItemNumber,dObjQuantity,'q-' + Number(i+2),dObj.ItemNumber,i+2);
  }
  html+='</table>';
  var orderObj={html:html};
  return orderObj;
}
```

And here's a sketch that I hope will help you to understand what's going on in here.

[image]

As I look at I'm not sure it helps at all.  But I'll leave for now.

Comment: What do you mean by the quotes, I don’t know what you mean

Comment: That didn't seem to help. I edited my post with a screenshot of the debug log for the function moveToOrder, which returned some errors. getInventory did not return any errors I hope this is helpful

Comment: I edited my post to include a screenshot of all sheets and the dialog. I have also included the full code, excluding the html pages, which have not been changed.

Comment: Obviously `orderObj` is undefined but since I can't see all of the code and run it and look at console and Logger.log, I can't really help you.  Perhaps someone else can.

Comment: This is the bad line you were missing the id number for quantity textbox and you still need to figure out what you want to  send to the javascript `moveToOrder()` function and now that you have more items I'm not what you want. 
    `html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td><input type="text" value="%s" id="%s" size="6" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Order" onClick="moveToOrder(\'%s\',\'%s\');"/></tr>',pA[i][0],pA[i][1],pA[i][2].toString().replace(/(")/g,'\\"'),pA[i][3],pA[i][4],'q-' + Number(i+2),pA[i][2],i+2);`

Comment: Ran out of room.  But I just wanted to say that you have keep in mind that although this code is created in the google script file it's inserted in the html file.

Comment: What does this line do? Does it add the quantity value entered in the dialog to the array of the rest of the part info? `pA[0].splice(pA[0].length,0,orderObj.quantity);` Also, I am fairly certain there is an issue with the button because when I run it from the script editor, it copies everything except the quantity, but the button does nothing

Comment: Yes. Here's a [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: "you still need to figure out what you want to send to the javascript moveToOrder() function and now that you have more items I'm not what you want. " How do I set what I want to send? I want to send the brand, product description, size and type, and item number of the item I clicked order on then I want the function to splice on the inputted quantity and print it.